# mod_rewrite a .html to a subdomain

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Morning everyone,

I'm really hoping someone can help. I've redeveloped a html website into a php website and I want to use mod_rewrite.

I'm probably being really stupid (as you can see though I'm very new to this!) but I promised I've googled about but can't see the answer.

What I need to do is redirect my old crappy .html files to a virtual subdomain.

So Example.html needs to go to example.mydomain.co.uk (I only have a couple of pages so I think I can get away without using expressions).

I got as close as:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule example.html$ ^example\.mydomain\.co.uk [R=301,NC]
```

but that just does mydomain.co.uk\%5eexample.mydomain.co.uk.  I've found tons of examples to then push the domain to php so that bits sorted it just this first bit!

Many many thanks in advance for all your help.

Regards, Alan

Comment: try this : [rewrite guide](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want anything which begins with only a-z lowercase letters to be redirected to the subdomain, then this will do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.html$ $1.mydomain.co.uk [R=permanent]
```

However, you need to think carefully about whether there are any .html files which must not be redirected. In such cases you'll need to identify whether there is a pattern which can be easily avoided, in which case a change of the regular expression may be all that is needed. If there is no pattern which allows you to easily avoid these non-redirect pages, then you'll probably need to use RewriteCond and add checks in for each page for which you want to avoid a redirect.